# Ignore precompiled headers, should I?

Tags: c++, c++17, qt-creator

On QtCreator, Options, C++, Code Model, General I see the following option

```
Ignore precompiled headers
```

And there is a tooltip on mouse hover.

I read about PCH on https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-precompiledheaders.html, but I would like to know the implications of this checkbox? It says

```
parsing for code completition
and semantic highlighting
will process the precompiled header before processing any file
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use precompiled headers (C/C++)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903228/why-use-precompiled-headers-c-c)

Comment: [Precompiled headers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4954167/995714), [Why use precompiled headers (C/C++)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/903228/995714), [Precompiled Headers? Do we really need them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1138301/995714)

Comment: No. These links are about the pros/cons of PCH, question is about that checkbox on QtCreator.