# Trying to set up a pre-compiled header

Tags: gcc, g++, precompiled-headers

```
fatal error: can't create precompiled header stdc++.h.gch: Permission denied
```

I'm getting the above error while using the command  `g++ -std=c++14 stdc++.h` on windows powershell in the directory where stdc++.h is located. How do I fix this ?

Comment: Have you tried running the command as an administrator?

Comment: Added an answer to the post, as it may help people in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run Powershell as an administrator and it should work fine - you gain all permissions you need.

Comment: Is this a good idea on Windows? I know that doing this on macOS or Linux would generally be a bad idea (except perhaps for shared installations) — the real answer would be to fix file ownership/permissions and/or changing the installation location. But maybe on Windows this is handled differently.

Comment: To be honest - I do not know. It is probably not too safe, as it may potentially cause some problems, but it is the solution for not having enough permissions.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to consider here.

- Administrative privilege
- Precompiled header

---

The solution to the first one is easy. You are trying to make changes in a system directory. I assume the following attempt will succeed but I cannot test.

1. Create `my_pch.hpp` that contains the following line in desktop or any other user directory.

   ```cpp
   #include <stdc++.h>
   ```
2. Compile the header in that directory.

   ```
   g++ -std=c++14 my_pch.hpp
   ```

You should get the same precompiled header.

---

You should ask yourself why you need a precompiled header. Answers on [do we really need precompiled headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138301/precompiled-headers-do-we-really-need-them) mentions about the effect of the size of the project, reduction in compile time, but facing with further problems. If you are unsure, it is advised not using them.